# how can I insert values in table using pattern matching from other tables in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a new column in the table using reference from another table e.g 
element A.x has to be added in table A taking element B.X from table B where B.y="some string"   as well as the other elements of table A are to be inserted using other tables C,D in a similar fashion

Comment: Can you show some example data and the expected results? I have no idea what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question leaves room for interpretation.

Could look like this if "other elements" refer to additional columns:

```
INSERT INTO a (x, col1, col2)
SELECT b.x, c.col1, d.col2
FROM   b
JOIN   c ON <join-condition>
JOIN   d ON <join-condition>
WHERE  b.y = "some string";
```

Or like this if "other elements" refer to additional rows:

```
INSERT INTO a (x)
SELECT x FROM b WHERE y = "some string"

UNION ALL
SELECT x FROM c WHERE y = "some string"

UNION ALL
SELECT x FROM d WHERE y = "some string";
```